# Split each string into multiple strings in a vector

Tags: r, strsplit

```
fruits <- c("apple", "orange", "pear")
df <- data.frame(string = c("appleorange",
                        "orangepear",
                        "applepear"))
```

Desired outcome:

| string |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| appleorange | apple | orange |
| orangepear | orange | pear |
| applepear | apple | pear |

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using regex along with `sub`:

```r
regex <- paste0("(?:", paste(fruits, collapse="|"), ")")
df$col1 <- sub(paste0(regex, "$"), "", df$string)
df$col2 <- sub(paste0("^", regex), "", df$string)
df

       string   col1   col2
1 appleorange  apple orange
2  orangepear orange   pear
3   applepear  apple   pear
```

**Data:**

```
fruits <- c("apple", "orange", "pear")
df <- data.frame(string = c("appleorange", "orangepear", "applepear"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `stringr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_extract(string, paste(fruits, collapse = '|')),
         col2 = str_replace(string, col1, ''))
```

```
       string   col1   col2
1 appleorange  apple orange
2  orangepear orange   pear
3   applepear  apple   pear
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df, string, into = c("col1", "col2"), 
   sep = glue::glue("(?<=[a-z])(?={str_c(fruits, collapse='|')})"), remove = FALSE)
       string   col1   col2
1 appleorange  apple orange
2  orangepear orange   pear
3   applepear  apple   pear
```